# ASP.NET Core MVC works only with Json-Files with 1 object in it

Tags: c#, arrays, json.net, asp.net-core-mvc

**I am not sure how to explain my problem corectly but I will try my best.** 
My MVC accepts Json-Files like this one

```
{
  "userId": 1,
  "id": 1,
  "title": "delectus aut autem",
  "completed": false
}
```

but not Json-Files with more than one "Object" in it

```
[
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "delectus aut autem",
    "completed": false
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "title": "quis ut nam facilis et officia qui",
    "completed": false
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 3,
    "title": "fugiat veniam minus",
    "completed": false
  }
]
```

This is my MVC and this way it works but when I replace the URL (https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos) to have a Json-File with more than 1 "Object" in it my Webpage gives me an Error.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using ToDo.Models;
using System.Net;

namespace ToDo.Controllers
{
    public class ToDoData : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult ToDoModel()
        {
            var webClient = new WebClient();
            webClient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, "cookievalue");
            var json = webClient.DownloadString(@"https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1");
            ToDoStructure ToDoData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ToDoStructure>(json);

            return View(ToDoData);
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone help with this problem?

The Error:

```
JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array 
(e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'ToDo.Models.ToDoStructure' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize 
correctly. To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object 
(e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or 
a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) 
like List<T> that can be deserialized from a JSON array. 
JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to 
deserialize from a JSON array. Path '', line 1, position 1.
```

The Razor-Page where I want to display the data as a Table

```
@model ToDo.Models.ToDoStructure
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ToDoModel";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<h2>ToDoModel</h2>
@{ 
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>userId</th>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>title</th>
        <th>completed</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>@Model.userId</th>
        <th>@Model.id</th>
        <th>@Model.title</th>
        <th>@Model.completed</th>
    </tr>
</table>
}
```

Comment: And you want to make it so it accepts more than one...right?

Comment: what error are you getting ?

Comment: Yeah I want it to accept more than one

Comment: So, `.DeserializeObject<List<ToDoStructure>>` ?

Comment: With this I get an Error in VS:  Error: CS0029 | File: ToDoData.cs | Line: 15| Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<ToDo.Models.ToDoStructure>' to 'ToDo.Models.ToDoStructure'

Comment: You will also need to change the type of `ToDoData` to match i.e. `List<ToDoStructure> ToDoData = ...`, or use `var` and the type will change automatically for you.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly but with this I don't get an error in VS :`List<ToDoStructure> ToDoData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ToDoStructure>>(json);` but the Webpage has a new one: `InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List``1[ToDo.Models.ToDoStructure]', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'ToDo.Models.ToDoStructure'.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want only two (generic) JSON models, you need use:

```
var _todoData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<>>(json)
```

In this case, `_todoData` will be a list.

Then, in your view, you need use `_todoData`, and in your HTML, `tr` needs a foreach, since you will now be working with a list! (This is what the error is saying.)

Comment: `public class ToDoData : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult ToDoModel()
        {
            var webClient = new WebClient();
            webClient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, "cookievalue");
            var json = webClient.DownloadString(@"https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos");
            var _toDoData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ToDoStructure>>(json);

            return View(_toDoData);
        }
    }` I did this but what do I need to change in ToDoModel.cshtml

Comment: on frontend, when you create table tr you need foreach

Comment: After I used `@model List<ToDo.Models.ToDoStructure>` and `@foreach (var t in Model)` everything worked fine. Thank you very much. I would give you an upvoe but I don't have enough reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Try to receive it into string before deserializing it to the expected list object. follow the below format and revert back:

string responseBody = webClient.DownloadString(urladdress);
JavaScriptSerializer json_serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();//or json serializer

List items =
json_serializer.Deserialize<List>(responseBody);
foreach (var item in items)
{
//loop through if need be

```
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use a list

```
List<ToDoStructure> ToDoData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ToDoStructure>>(json);
```

and fix model too

```
@model  List<ToDo.Models.ToDoStructure>
```